# c++ symbols received from backtrace_symbols does not show function in g++

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, g++, backtrace

I'm trying to print a backtrace in code progrematically, compiling all my source with -g, as well as linking with it, and I also added fvisibility=internal.

but when I call the symbol list, all my code looks like:

module() [0x424b69]

why does the function name does not appear in the braces, what other possible flag should I add?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use

```
-rdynamic
```

Something like:

```
g++ -g -rdynamic main.cpp
```

From http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html:

> -rdynamic
>       Pass the flag -export-dynamic to the ELF linker, on targets that support it. This instructs the linker to add all symbols, not only
>   used ones, to the dynamic symbol table. This option is needed for some
>   uses of dlopen or **to allow obtaining backtraces from within a program**.